# How to migrate mysql database from old schema to new?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

I have old mysql db with data. A new schema is developed with few changes. Some fields in some tables are removed and new tables are added. What is the best way to bring data from old db to new one only where fields are unchanged?

Comment: The best way is to only ever make schema changes with programmed migrations and a migration library. I guess you aren't using one?

Comment: problem is when I am applying migrations using previous migration files, many errors are showing up. so cant go through in that way

Comment: Then you should fix the migration files. This is by far the best solution. Make sure you have working migrations to get to your current database schema, then make sure you have additional migrations to get to the new one.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Trying the same

Answer (score -1):

Look into `SELECT INTO` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp).

```
SELECT *
INTO new_table [IN externaldb]
FROM old_table
WHERE condition;
```